# failed to run python program (anaconda package) remotely with gnu parallel

Tags: python, anaconda, gnu-parallel

It seems the python environment installed by anaconda is not assessable through gnu parallel remotely:

```
seq 1 1 | parallel -S 8/192.168.0.93 python -V
Python 2.6.6
```

But the anaconda version is

```
python -V
Python 2.7.8 :: Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit)
```

Here is my problem. I am running a python program (myprog.py), which depends on the packages installed by anaconda. It runs well on the single remote machines, but when I put the execution on multiple machines through gnu parallel as the following,

```
parallel -S 8/${server1},8/${server2},8/${server3},8/${server4} --workdir ${pydir} --linebuffer --header : \
  python myprog.py {arg} \
  ::: arg ${args[@]}
```

I get the error

```
ImportError: No module named tables
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `anaconda` set the path and/or other environment variables? Try:

```
echo $PATH
ssh 192.168.0.93 echo '$PATH'
seq 1 1 | parallel --env PATH -S 8/192.168.0.93 python -V
```